# limit 'date of birth' form field numerical inputs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to limit my custom 'Date of Birth' form field. To only accept realistic dates - *ie*. **Day = 1 - 31 Month = 1-12**. I have tried using `max` attribute but it doesn't work. *(not sure if it's because I'm also using maxlength?)*

```
<div id="date2" class="datefield">
    <input id="day" name="BirthDate" type="BirthDate" maxlength="2" placeholder="DD" style="width:10%;" max="31" required /> /
    <input id="month" name="BirthDate" type="BirthDate" maxlength="2" placeholder="MM" style="width:10%;" max="12" required /> /
    <input id="year" name="BirthDate" type="BirthDate" maxlength="4" placeholder="YYYY" style="width:18%;" required />
</div>
```

any suggestions?

*Sorry! I cannot use drop-downs! Due to API.*

Also, I cannot simply use `type="date"` (I wish) because it displays really poorly with custom design / styles.

Comment: How about using `<input type="date" />`?

Comment: date sounds awesome. But my form field is custom, styled with a div wrapper and custom css to break into 3 numerical section to meet design needs. SImply using 'date' displaying really badly with design.

Comment: if user enter max value as 32 in date would you like to show error message or clean that text box and display as zero.

Comment: If you need type=text, then use regex to check input values...

Comment: If you use min and max attributes + a regular HTML form submit, validation will happen on form submission. It just doesn't happen as the user types data.

Comment: If you are not going to use a built-in date picker (e.g. by using type="date") then you will probably want some javascript code to validate your dates. Just using a max of 31 for days would still allow February 31 to be a valid date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the input type to "number" and set min and max values. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/snc7mLhc/).

```
<div id="date2" class="datefield">
    <input id="day" name="BirthDate" type="number" placeholder="DD" style="width:10%;" min="1" max="31" required /> /
    <input id="month" name="BirthDate" type="number" placeholder="MM" style="width:10%;" min="1" max="12" required /> /
    <input id="year" name="BirthDate" type="number" maxlength="4" placeholder="YYYY" style="width:18%;" required />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually better practice is to use drop-down menus for date/month/year instead of freeform input fields - it also spares you need to validate input upon submitting form. You also will not lose any functionality, because dropdown also accepts numeric input (if user clicks or tab's in this field and uses numeric keys to input date/month, list will simply jump to entered position in dropdown - no difference from plain input field).

Of course, if you insist on using freeform input field, you can use input type number `<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">` or you can just use one of many available JavaScript plugins created exactly for this purpose. Just google for 'datepicker plugin'.

There is also field type `<input type="date" />` but it's not supported in older browsers and some mobile browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged your question with "HTML5", I would suggest using `<input type="date" name="bday">` as described here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_date